# Laravel how to get object after and before saving this?

Tags: laravel, save

I'm using Laravel 4.2

My model has a function like this:

```
ServiceLog::saved(function($servicelog) {
   if($servicelog->date_created != $old_date_created) {
      //do something here
   }
});
```

I want to compare the value of the field `date_created` after and before saving $servicelog

How do I get the $old_date_created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `getDirty()` and `isDirty()` methods according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getDirty). `isDirty` checks if given attribute has changed and `getDirty` returns the attributes, that have been changed. You also have `getOriginal()` method, which will return the previous value of given attribute (before the change).

What you can do is this:

```
ServiceLog::saving(function($model)
{
    // Check if property has changed
    if ($model->isDirty('date_created')) {
        // Get the original value before the change
        $oldDate = $model->getOriginal('date_created');
        // Get current value for date_changed
        $newDate = $model->date_created;
        echo "The date_created changed from $oldDate to $newDate";
    }

    return true; //if false the model won't save! 
});
```

Comment: Why not just use `$model->isDirty('date_created')`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter You are right. Thanks for the correction.